# Changing Button Color on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am having a little problem with my code.

I want when the user clicks on any button it changes its color to the hover color and text color to white.

And when the user click the next button the previous one will come back to its previous state. Is it possible?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 2px solid #1A6893;
  margin-top:20px;
  color: #1A6893;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}


a {
  color: #1A6893;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#button-3 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button-3 a {
  position: relative;
  transition: all .45s ease-Out;
}

#circle {
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1A6893;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease-Out;
  top: 20px;
  left: 70px;
  color:#FFF;
}

#button-3:hover #circle {
  width: 200%;
  height: 500%;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -70px;
  left: -70px;
}

#button-3:hover a {
  color: #FFF;
}
.abc{
 margin-top:20px;
 
 }
.boxes {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #484848;
}

/*Checkboxes styles*/
input[type="checkbox"] { display: none; }

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font: 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #1a6893;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #1a6893;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .6;
  -webkit-transition: all .12s, border-color .08s;
  transition: all .12s, border-color .08s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  width: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
} 
.button:active{
 color:#039;
 background-color:#396;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="row" style="padding:0px;">
  <div class="col-1"><div class="button" id="button-3" onClick="changeColor();"><div id="circle"></div><a href="#">Day</a></div></div>
        <div class="col-1"><div class="button" id="button-3"><div id="circle"></div><a href="#">Week</a></div></div>
        <div class="col-1"><div class="button" id="button-3"><div id="circle"></div><a href="#">Month</a></div></div>
        <div class="col-1"><div class="button" id="button-3"><div id="circle"></div><a href="#">Day Sheet</a></div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is your `changeColour();` function

Comment: You will need Javascript.

Comment: No he use :focus attribute for buttons

Comment: Isn't the :active pseudo class what you are looking for? See! https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Answer (score 2):

Just add some rules for the "active" state.

Also, I changed all your IDs to classes. You should only provided unique identifiers in the ID attribute.

Furthermore, I changed the `button-3:hover .circle` rule to `button-3:not(.active):hover .circle`. This hides the animation of the circle when hovering over "active" buttons.

```css
.button.active {
  background-color: #396;
}

.button.active a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.button-3:not(.active):hover .circle {
  width: 200%;
  height: 500%;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -70px;
  left: -70px;
}
```

Then listen for the click, toggle the "active" class from all buttons:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button')).forEach(button => {
  button.classList.toggle('active', button === e.currentTarget);
}
```

### Example

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button')).forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
});

function handleButtonClick(e) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button')).forEach(button => {
    button.classList.toggle('active', button === e.currentTarget);
  });
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 2px solid #1A6893;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #1A6893;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button.active {
  background-color: #396;
}
.button.active a {
  color: #FFF;
}

a {
  color: #1A6893;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.button-3 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-3 a {
  position: relative;
  transition: all .45s ease-Out;
}

.circle {
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1A6893;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease-Out;
  top: 20px;
  left: 70px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.button-3:not(.active):hover .circle {
  width: 200%;
  height: 500%;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -70px;
  left: -70px;
}

.button-3:hover a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.abc {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.boxes {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #484848;
}


/*Checkboxes styles*/

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font: 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #1a6893;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #1a6893;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .6;
  -webkit-transition: all .12s, border-color .08s;
  transition: all .12s, border-color .08s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  width: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.button:active {
  color: #039;
  background-color: #396;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="padding:0px;">
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="button button-3">
      <div class="circle"></div><a href="#">Day</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="button button-3">
      <div class="circle"></div><a href="#">Week</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="button button-3">
      <div class="circle"></div><a href="#">Month</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="button button-3">
      <div class="circle"></div><a href="#">Day Sheet</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not quite work. I tried `.button:not(.clicked):active {` to make the hover not do anything if clicked

Comment: @mplungjan So you want the hover effect to be disabled for active?

Comment: OP seems to want that? `it changes its color to the hover color and text color to white.`

Comment: Change the `#button-3:hover #circle` rule to `#button-3:not(.active):hover #circle`

Comment: Also the code still has duplicate IDs

Comment: @mplungjan Hey listen, I am not here to write the application for OP, just pointed out how to toggle an active state.

Comment: Sure... But I deleted my answer which had these changes, because yours seemed to do the job. Hence my comments

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, I addressed this. Thanks.